# How to restrict property type to be percentage?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to set a type of variable that can only receive percentage values. for example:

let value: string | number.

If the user passes a string to this variable value, the typescript can only receive with this pattern

```
value= "30%"
```

If the user passes

```
value= "foo"
```

the typescript should show an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use template literal types:

```
type Percentage = `${number}%` | number
```

Comment: I am using above mentioned type Percentage and getting error on performing any arithmetic operation.
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'number'.ts(2365)

where cx: Percentage | number;
const sx = cx + (outerRadius + 10) * cos;

Comment: you probably don't want to allow `'10%' + 10`